# Why does C++ allows assigning an map iterator to a iterator of a map with different comparator?

Tags: c++, std

I am confused why the following code compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int, std::less<int>> m {{1,10}, {2,20}};
    std::map<int,int, std::greater<int>>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    it++;
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

I assumed C++ would be "strongly typed" in this regard, and disallow me to assign to an iterator of another map type.

I [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/Ya1n7Edfr) with C++23 switch, but standard version does not seem to affect it.

note: I presume map iterator does not need to know about comparison since it just needs to know how to go to previous/next and dereference, but still seems weird this compiles.

edit: I see `const_iterator` is "type erasing" but I would like to know why.

cpp reference:

> const_iterator    LegacyBidirectionalIterator to const value_type

Comment: I'm puzzled why this confuses you. Do you think this should *never* work and two pieces of code must use the exact same name for a type or it shouldn't compile? If `a::foo_type` and `b::foo_type` are known to both be `int&`, shouldn't they interoperate smoothly? So should it fail to compile if they just happen to be the same type? How do you imagine the two types differ?! If you were coding `std::map`, how would you cram the comparator's type into the iterator's type?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have edited my question. My point is why allow this to compile. For sure it is confusing for readers, even though it might work without undefined behavior at runtime. For example I would expect that incremeting my iterator will always give me value that is less than current, but that is not true since I am actually iterating in a map that is ordered by less, not greater.

Comment: as a N of 1 story: I was recently editing some code that had 2 maps, one ordered by less and one by greater, and the iterator type was explicitly written out, and in one case it was just wrong(greater instead of less or vice versa, I dont remember).

Comment: I just think your intuition is bizarre. If I have two containers of `int`'s, surely `container1<int,void>::value_type`, `container2<int,bool>::value_type` and `int` should all work exactly the same.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I disagree(in  a sense I do not see it like that, you can see it like that if you want :), it is personal opinion not something mesurable).     Iterators are not just value_type, they are used for iterating and iteration in a map has certain guarantees. If iterator is not .end() and comparator is less when you increment the value you will either get an .end() or an iterator to a value that is greater than current. 
Allowing code like this to compiles breaks this "requirement".

Comment: The trees' structure in the map is built upon inserting and removing from the map. Iterating is just walking the tree, which is the same process regardless of the order of the elements in the tree.

Comment: @NathanOliver pointer and a reference are implemented as pointer.  enums(proper ones, enum class) are usually just ints.  I still expect C++ to not allow me to mix reference/pointer or enum/int .

Comment: But that's just it, you're not mixing anything.  Deep down, both containers are storing the elements of the maps as `struct node { std::pair<const int,int> data, ...};`, so both iterators are pointing to the same thing.  the comparator only matters to the map itself, so you can't do something like `std::map<int,int, std::greater<int>> mg = m;`

Comment: @NathanOliver I cant explain it more clear that I did. And I see your point, but I disagree. :)  So I know what you are saying, but my point is that incrementing an map iterator is not just getting a next item in a tree.. It has certain requirements  I mentioned in the answer to David. Now obviously C++/STL disagrees with me on that, but I still think it should be enforced that you can not mix iterators of maps with different comparators.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I'm not understanding your replay to David.  You say that if the comparator is less then you should get a greater value when you increment, and that's what your getting.  `m`'s comparator is `less`, so when you increment an iterator from `begin`, you get the next greater element.  There is no comparator as far as the iterator is concerned.  both containers return `std::iterator<std::pair<const int, int>>`

Comment: @NathanOliver just read this code without knowing where it  gets it's value from and assume we do not hit .end() :   std::map<int,int, std::greater<int>>::const_iterator it = /*...*/; auto val1 = *it; it++; auto val2 = *it;  assert(val1>val2);  I think this assert should always pass.  But that is not always true since I can assign what I want to that iterator(including .begin() from map ordered by less)

Comment: The search term for further research is [SCARY iterators](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2911.pdf)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that is actually an answer. Not that I agree with Bjarne or the others, but it answers my question. Feel free to answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not require an iterator's type to be unique for a particular instantiation of a container template. All it says about `C::iterator` where `C` is a container is that it is:

> iterator type whose value type is `T`

Different containers impose different iterator requirements, and specific containers have more specific definitions, but with regard to exactly what type it is, this is pretty much it. An implementation can comply with this requirement however it wishes. Iterators into the same template that has a different allocator may have a different type... or it may not (though supporting some of the more esoteric aspects of allocators may require them to have different types). And this is even more the case for template parameters that have nothing to do with iteration.

You cannot rely on these being the same type. But the standard isn't going to deny implementations the ability to optimize code by not having to instantiate multiple types that are completely identical for no reason.